# Can I change the Organization name and Unit in keystore after generating keystore file in android?

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I have one application live.
Now I want to change the organization name in keystore file
Is it possible to change organization name

Comment: If you never upload your apk on the play store, You can create new KeyStore  otherwise it is not possible to update current keyStore file

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I am also thinking like that but I am clear now
 thanks